# save result of for_each algorithm inside a vector

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I have a functor and the overloaded `operator()` of it returns a `double`. In an easy way I can write:

```
int main(){
    auto f=[](double  t){return 1.0/(pow(7.0*t,2.0)+1.0);};
    std::vector<double> nodes(n);
    bestpolchevnod(f,nodes); //calculate nodes = f_i(cheby_point(i))
    ChebyPoly c_p = ChebyPoly(nodes);//call the constructor with the calculated nodes
    std::cout << c_p(0.6) << std::endl; //evaluate at c_p(0.6) as an approx of f(0.6)
};
```

Now it is possible to go through a set of values by using `for_each()` like:

```
std::vector<double> xpoints={0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7};
std::for_each(xpoints.begin(), xpoints.end(), ChebyPoly(nodes));
```

Is there a sharp/short way to save the calculated values of this algorithm directly for example in a vector? I know there are ways to do it otherwise. But I wonder if there is something similar like

```
std::vector<double> resvec(xpoints.size());
resvec.push_back(std::for_each(xpoints.begin(), xpoints.end(), ChebyPoly(nodes))); // wrong
```

Comment: No, there's no a clean way to do exactly what you've asked for, because `std::for_each` is the wrong tool for the job. The right tool for this job is `std::transform`.

Comment: You can use `std::vector::back_inserter` with `std::transform`. See example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform.

Comment: BTW - isn't `ChebyPoly` supposed to be dependent on `xpoints` element ?

Comment: thank you. No it depends on the `nodes`. It is like I(t)=foTo(t) + f1T1(t) +...+fnTn(t). And here the `t` stands for the `xpoints`. And Tn are the Chebychev Polynoms and fi are the function values at the cheby-node position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::for_each` is the wrong algorithm, you want `std::transform`

```
std::vector<double> resvec(xpoints.size());
std::transform(xpoints.begin(), xpoints.end(), resvec.begin(), ChebyPoly(nodes));
```

Or without zero-initialising the elements of `resvec`

```
std::vector<double> resvec;
resvec.reserve(xpoints.size());
std::transform(xpoints.begin(), xpoints.end(), std::back_inserter(resvec), ChebyPoly(nodes));
```

Or without allocating a result, instead having a lazy view

```
auto result = xpoints | std::ranges::views::transform(ChebyPoly(nodes));
```